# Having trouble with Scanner class

Tags: java, serialization, io, java.util.scanner, fileoutputstream

I am using Scanner class to get a file name. But my Scanner s is not even asking me any string. It just set the entered string to ""(empty String). Then I get file not found exception.Also another question is, I am using FileOutputStream to write a file. Isn't it should create the file if not exists ? Here is part of my code where I use scanner.

```
else if(user_choice == 3){
                System.out.println("kaydedilecek dosyanın ismini giriniz : ");
                String file_name = s.nextLine();
                IOdata iod = new IOdata(data);
                iod.save_data(file_name);
```

and the below code is about io.

```
public void save_data(String file_name) throws IOException {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file_name);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(data);
            oos.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            file_name = "default";
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file_name);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(data);
            oos.close();
        }
    }
```

Edit full of my Menu class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {
    public Menu() throws IOException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Data data = new Data();
        while(true){
            System.out.println("1-data oluştur");
            System.out.println("2-datayı yükle");
            System.out.println("3-datayı kaydet");
            System.out.println("4-çıkış");
            System.out.println("5-yazdır");
            int user_choice = s.nextInt();
            if(user_choice == 4) {
                break;
            }else if(user_choice == 1){
                DataManupilator dm = new DataManupilator(data);
                System.out.println("datanın uzunluğunu giriniz : ");
                int length = s.nextInt();
                data = dm.generate_data(length);
            }else if(user_choice == 5){
                data.print_items();
            }else if(user_choice == 3){
                System.out.println("kaydedilecek dosyanın ismini giriniz : ");
                String file_name = s.nextLine();
                IOdata iod = new IOdata(data);
                iod.save_data(file_name);
            }else if(user_choice == 2){
                System.out.println("datanın bulunduğu dosyanın ismini giriniz : ");
                String file_name = s.nextLine();
                IOdata iod = new IOdata(data);
                iod.save_data(file_name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is some turkish Strings in my code so let me explain. If user chooses 3 program goes to write data to a file.

Comment: We need more information. How do you create the scanner? What are you scanning/How do you get the input?

Comment: Did you declare the scanner like this Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)?

Comment: I edited to add full code of my Menu class. nNow you can see.

Comment: @am0awad yes I used that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to enter the choice nubmer`int user_choice = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());`

Comment: it worked. But im curious about how scanner works. Scanner is only compatible with 1 type of value ? I mean, am I need 2 scanner to get 2 different type of values.

Comment: Because of `parseInt()` reads just the number, not the entire line, if you want to use it. put `nextLine()`

Comment: @BaranSAHİN - I recommend that you read the javadoc for `Scanner` or find a tutorial that explains how it works.  It is far more efficient and effective (as a way of learning) for you to do some reading than for us to give you personal tuition via comments, or whatever.

Comment: I searched on the internet about Scanner. I couldn't understand exactly how it is works. Because source code is more complicated than i thought but my problem fixed. Thank you for your helps.